# Livecd (liveusb) ramdisk size

Tags: live-usb

What is the boot kernel option (casper) to change the size of the ram root file system when booting from livecd. I want to be able to install few packages to work with, w/o really installing the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the writable portion of the usb by a boot kernel option. What you need to do is to expand the persistent file system on the usb drive, the `casper-rw` file. See [this tutorial](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/) for a step by step explanaition.